# UMP size $\alpha$ hypothesis test for discrete distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, discrete-data

Let $\left(Z_1, \ldots Z_n\right)$ be an i.i.d. sample with common probability mass function
$$
p_Z(j)=\vartheta^2 I_{[j=1]}+2 \vartheta(1-\vartheta) I_{[j=2]}+(1-\vartheta)^2 I_{[j=3]}
$$

Find a UMP size $\alpha$ hypothesis test for $H_0: \vartheta=1 / 3$ versus $H_A: \vartheta> 1/3$. Give an explicit formula determining the constant threshold in the rejection region.

$\textbf{My Attempt}:$

The joint distribution is given by:$$ p_z(\textbf{j}) = 2^{n_2}\vartheta^{2n_1 - n_2} (1 - \vartheta)^{2n - (2n_1 + n_2)}$$
where $n_1 = \text{# of $Z_i$ such that j = 1}$ and $n_2 = \text{# of $Z_i$ such that j = 2}$

By Factorization Theorem, $$T = 2n_1 + n_2$$

For $\vartheta_2 > \vartheta_1$ we can show that there is a monotone likelihood ratio in our sufficient statistic $2n_1 + n_2$, and so Karlin-Rubin Theorem tells us that we
$$\text{Reject $H_0$ if $2n_1 + n_2$ > k}$$
$$\text{Reject $H_0$ with probability $\gamma$ if $2n_1 + n_2$ = k}$$
$$\text{Do not reject $H_0$ if $2n_1 + n_2$ < k}$$
Where k is a constant such that:$$\alpha = P(2n_1 + n_2 > k| \vartheta = \frac13) + \gamma P(2n_1 + n_2 = k| \vartheta = \frac13)$$

$\textbf{Where I get stuck}$: Now I want to solve for k but this second term with the auxiliary randomization is making it very difficult. I am also not sure what the distribution of $2n_1 + n_2$. I assume here that it will be a binomial and we can make use of the normal approximation to the binomial.

$$ \text{Under $H_0$}~ n_1 \sim bin(n, \frac19),~ n_2 \sim bin(n, \frac49) $$
$$ E_{H_0}(2n_1 + n_2) = \frac{2n}{9} + \frac{4n}{9} = \frac{2n}{3}$$
$$ Var_{H_0}(2n_1 + n_2) = 4Var(n_1) + Var(n_2) = \frac{32n}{81} + \frac{20n}{81} = \frac{52n}{81}$$

So: $$\alpha = P(\frac{T - \frac{2n}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{52n}{81}}} > \frac{k - \frac{2n}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{52n}{81}}}) + \gamma P(\frac{T - \frac{2n}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{52n}{81}}} = \frac{k - \frac{2n}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{52n}{81}}})$$ $$ = 1 - pnorm(\frac{k - \frac{2n}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{52n}{81}}}) + \gamma ~dnorm(\frac{k - \frac{2n}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{52n}{81}}})$$

I am not sure how to solve for k from here on. Assuming there is large n could I simply ignore the auxiliary randomization term? Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider that $(n_1,n_2)$ has a multinomial distribution. You are assuming $n_1$ and $n_2$ are independent under $H_0$, which I am not sure is true.